# Team Foundation Server file deprecating

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, deprecated

Our environment uses the ODP.Net oracle database driver.
So logically we are using Oracle on the backend.

We have files that include scripts of our stored procedures in TFS.

My oracle developer would like to deprecate a file to keep other oracle developers from using it in the future but also of course he would like to keep it in source in case he decides to come back to using it later.

Now deprecating a .Net class is a matter of using the Obselete tag and I am not discussing in this scenario doing so.

This is a text file and our database developers are trying to play nicely with us as a team and just want to deprecate a text file in TFS.

So does TFS has something that essentially deprecates any file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete it. You'll still be able to retrieve the current version of the file in the future if it's needed later.

Comment: Yes. But remember DELETE not Destroy :-)